# Size overflow in allocator unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, overflow

I have a created a script for spawning enemies. And whenever I play it, for a couple of seconds unity works fine. The more enemies that are being spawned the slower unity gets. It keeps saying that; size overflow in allocator unity. 
What does this mean? I tried going through stack overflow, In my case, I can't seem to find the reason why this is happening.

```
Vector2 whereToSpawn;
float randomX;
[SerializeField] float spawnRate;
[SerializeField] float nextSpawn;
[SerializeField] float randomSpawnx, randomSpawny;
private void Spawn() 
{ 
 //if (Time.time > nextSpawn)
     { 
      nextSpawn = Time.time + spawnRate;
      randomX = Random.Range(randomSpawnx, randomSpawny); 
      whereToSpawn = new Vector2(randomX, transform.position.y);
      Instantiate(enemy, whereToSpawn, Quaternion.identity);
     } 
}
```

Comment: Please add the code you think is responsible for the error. Refer to [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Spawn method gets called inside the update method.

Comment: Well `Update` ist called **every frame** probably you simply run out of RAM

Comment: I had a feeling. So I've to create a new method for it or should go under Fixed Update?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. 
Created an Invoke method and called it from Start.